# More efficient way of redirecting multiple directives in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to do multiple things with my .htaccess  --

I am trying to redirect multiple domains to a single domain

I am trying to redirect `non-www` to `www`

I am trying to redirect `non-https` to `https`

For this example -- I am wanting to achieve `https://myfinaldomain.com`

So far my htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example1.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example1.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example2.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example2.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example3.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example3.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example4.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example4.com [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://myfinaldomain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC] 

 # Redirect www and http to https - non-www version of https://myfinaldomain.com

            RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
            RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
            RewriteRule ^Home\.htm?$ / [NC,R,L]
```

My issues are, I can get this to work if I piece it out with `ifs` and such ...  If I use this as-is I get `too many redirects`.  Is there a more efficient way to look at all of this?  I already combined the `non-www` and `non-https` into a single block .. I am having trouble logically combining the top section all into a single set of `conditions` and a single `rule`.  Is this possible?

Comment: Just check if HTTPS is off or the host name is not `myfinaldomain.com` ...? Unless you need this in any kind of "dynamic" setup for multiple domains/VHosts, I don't see any need to use wildcards/variables for the latter.

Comment: Actually that is a great point .. this htaccess is being dynamically created for about 200 websites --  all of which have multiple domains, and ssl

Comment: even so -- Your thought -- checking `if not` domain  -- might do the trick .. Would you integrate that into the lower set of conditions?

Comment: Why is this happening on .htaccess level to begin with? In a halfway decent multi-site/multi-domain on single server setup I'd expect that to be dealt with on Virtual Host configuration level.

Comment: Because we deal with about 1000 sites .. Not all of which have multiple domains .. or ssl -- Only about 20% of our sites .. Which are created dynamically -  As are their vhost files .. This is the "admin" level of "adding domains" and "switching" a site to ssl

Comment: So by "multiple domains" you mean sub-domains of a "main" domain name only - so that the redirect target domain can always be inferred from the host name of the original request? And what does _"this htaccess is being dynamically created"_ actually mean? By what - some sort of (shell) script, that could be passed the actual redirect target domain simply as a parameter, if you'd not want to overly complicate things?

Comment: No .. We have over 2000 **domains** -- Not **sub domains**  -- I am adept enough that I would have specified.  We run over 1000 individual websites -- That said .. They are created by an admin panel that, yes, generates vhosts, htacces and file directory on the fly .. But sometimes a client may call an d want to add a domain to their website, or SSL for that matter.  However they have a primary that we always point to for SEO.  I think I  need to know how to: --> **if** it isn't the primary domain IE `https://thisdomain.com` --> **go to** primary domain.  Is this possible?

Comment: That's what I meant, whether there are multiple 2nd level domains pointing to the same "site" ... _"I think I need to know how to: --> if it isn't the primary domain IE `https://thisdomain.com`"_ - that was my question, where do you want to get the vaue `thisdomain.com` from in the first place, if the actual client request that led this far was made for `someotherdomain.com`? You will have to write that into the actual configuration file/section at some place. (Therefor my suggestion, to let a script called with appropriate parameters handle that.)

Comment: _"However they have a primary that we always point to for SEO."_ - and where/how do you store that value?

Comment: mysql database ..  primary = 1  --  So I see what you are saying .. Let the php handle the redirecting of domains .. Is that accurate?

Comment: No, not at all ... again, server configuration level is where I'd say this _should_ be placed, everything else later on has performance and security implications. Either a script that re-writes the necessary configuration section parts for the VHosts, fed from the database, and then makes Apache reload, run periodically or triggered manually; or, if possible. a hook into the admin panel directly that takes care of rewriting a specific VHost configuration only when the value is changed there